# can't get this sum of rationals working(Scala)

Tags: scala

alright , so im trying to do this example in a slide i found online. but im a little bit lost. heres a scan o f the problem

[a link](http://i5.photobucket.com/albums/y184/mnava18/nio_zpsdcdb8f7d.jpg)!

sorry it wont let me use the image link yet, so i put a link to the problem from my photobucket.

now i thought that this might be as easy as following the sum of ints example i found online and plugging in Rationals

```
def sum (f: Rational => Rational)( b: Rational): Rational = {  

    if (b > new Rational(0,1))  

        new Rational(0,1)  

    else  

        f(b) + sum(f)(b + new Rational(1, 1))  


}
```

and got that, but its apparently wrong and doesn't do what the question is asking. so now im lost an confused on how to go about this

Comment: What you've written isn't obviously connected with the algorithm on the slide. You need to get the numerator and denominator and call f on the combinations. How would you go about that?

Comment: As Paul stated, have you tried testing it? In your image it says that for b=3/4 it should return f(1/2)+...+ but your code returns 0 without recursion, as 3/4 > 0/1.

Comment: i did test it and got the wrong answers, i want to try and add print statements to see how each part is being used. but i have no idea how were to put them. everywere ive tried adding a print statement gets flagged for being wrong.

Comment: The last statement of a block of code is the return value of that block. Prints are of type Unit, which is not a Rational. You can put prnits in each branch of the if/else as long as you wrap the whole block with  {} and don't put them as last line of the block

Comment: It's always a good idea to mark homework with the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion, you can just iterate with a for. Something like:

```
val db = b.den
val partials = for {
  dk <- 2 to db
  nk <- 1 until dk
} yield f(Rational(nk, dk)
partials.sum
```

Comment: im kind of limited to using def sum (f: Rational => Rational)( b: Rational): Rational . since it says i must use that lol. but i see how that is way easier

Comment: This is the body of the sum function you need to define, i just omitted the declaration! ^_^